# Placemark - icon size GEplugin

Tags: c#, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

once agian i need help from all the kind users. 
Im using Interop.GEPlugin to develop an application to display certain points on the google earth globe, with different color circels. So far all of that is working, but the problem is the size of this placemark. i want i bigger, like alot!

The code to setting up the placemark is:

```
KmlIconCoClass icon1 = m_ge.createIcon("low");
icon1.setHref("http://www.wispresort.com/images/easier.jpg");
icon1.setW(3000);
icon1.setH(3000); 
var style = m_ge.createStyle("");
style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon1);
```

For some reason, when i only add either icon1.setH(3000) its getting higher, but when i add both it just goes back to the original size.. Did i misunderstand something? or is this just a simple mistake in the plug-in??

Hope you can help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GE plugin behaves strangley with icon sizes.  Even if you provide a large image as an icon, GE attempts to scale that icon down to a default size around 32 pixels.  The most effective way I have found to change the size of an icon is with the setScale() method of the kmlIconStyle. The scale is simply a multiplier.  If you want a 32px default icon size to bee 3000 pixels, then you can set the scale to about 94 (32x94=3008).  kmlIconScale.setScale(94);

```
KmlIconCoClass icon1 = m_ge.createIcon("low");
icon1.setHref("http://www.wispresort.com/images/easier.jpg"); 
var style = m_ge.createStyle("");
var iconStyle = style.getIconStyle();
iconStyle.setIcon(icon1);
iconStyle.setScale(98);
```

The other issue you will face is that GE will automatically scale icons to shrink as you zoom out, so there is so way I have found to make an icon stay at a set size at all scales

Documentation for [kmlIconStyle.setScale](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_icon_style?hl=it#a3fe5605aaf325b9ed04736218c99e68d)